# How to collapse groups of row values within a table using formattable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, formattable

I am interested in using tools within the `formattable` R package, but I want to only shows in the table where there is a change. That is, I want hierarchical row labeling that is offered in the `kableExtra` package via the `collapse_rows()` function.

For example, using `kable()` and `kableExtra`, I can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra) 

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  select(Species, everything()) %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  collapse_rows(1, valign="top")
```

to produce this:

[image: Iris table with rows grouped by Species]

However, I would like to do this using the `formattable` package and function so that I can run an arbitrary function over specific colums during output. Specifically, I want to add "sparklines" as a new column. I can do that using `knitr` and `formattble`, but then I lose the `collapse_rows`, as far as I can tell.

Is there any way to collapse rows in `formattable`?

Answer (score 8):

`collapse_rows` edits the kable object. If you have a [look at the code](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/blob/master/R/collapse_rows.R), it does a lot of different checks depending on the output format selected (HTML/PDF/text).

If you are looking for a more general method of collapsing the rows, we will have to edit the data.frame before the table is plotted. I have written a function `collapse_rows_df` which will collapse a specified column within your dataframe.

```
#' Collapse the values within a grouped dataframe
#' 
#' 
collapse_rows_df <- function(df, variable){

  group_var <- enquo(variable)

  df %>%
    group_by(!! group_var) %>%
    mutate(groupRow = 1:n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(!!quo_name(group_var) := ifelse(groupRow == 1, as.character(!! group_var), "")) %>%
    select(-c(groupRow))
}
```

Using this function, outputting to the formattable:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  select(Species, everything()) %>%
  collapse_rows_df(Species) %>%
  formattable()
```

[image]

> If you are confused by the use of `enquo()` or `quo_name()` within the function, you should check out how dplyr uses Non-standard evaluation: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: You should validate this answer, very good code here !!

Comment: Hello, this answers my question and works beautifully! However, I am not sure how it works. I am a beginner to midlevel R-user and have never seen :=, !!, enquo, or quo_name. Can someone explain to me how the function works?

Comment: Check out this from Hadley :) https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html .  As per the book, it's advanced R and I am not sure I fully get it still despite writing code with it :D