# Rmarkdown: Merge rows in a single column with without disturbing the rest of the table and export to excel

Tags: r, formatting, r-markdown

I have been trying to figure this out all morning. I want to collapse rows in a single column without summing the rest of the table. I don't know the proper terminology for what I am trying to do. I need to export the result to Excel, so I don't think I can use kableExtra to solve this as I normally would. Any suggestion will be helpful. The first table is what I have in R.
The second table is the desired product.

The data and my R-code is here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/156RqWANAu2wL-Tr-x_wsdZ_qjEgM_5jM?usp=sharing

[image: What I have]

[image: What I Want]

Comment: I think you can consider using `aggregate` function or `dplyr` package to group your data based on yoru criteria and then summerise it accordingly.

Comment: I think this solution is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450402/how-to-collapse-groups-of-row-values-within-a-table-using-formattable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)
# I assume that your data is in a data frame called 'df'
result <- df %>%
  group_by(DEPT, Degree) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
# Now you can write the result to an Excel file
write.xlsx(result, "output.xlsx")
```

You can use it with customized parameters in `across()` function.
This is brief letters and if you give me more information, I'd happy to help you!